# Inserindo coluna na tabela Oracle com condicional

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Preciso criar uma coluna em uma tabela existente mas preciso fazer com uma condição verificadora caso essa coluna já exista no banco eu fiz dessa maneira porém ele lança um erro:

```
DECLARE 
col_count  integer;
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*)
 into col_count
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = '<nomeTabela>'
AND column_name = '<nomeColuna>';

IF col_count = 0 THEN 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE <nomeTabela> add <nomeColuna> char(1) default 'A' not null';
 END IF;
END;
```

O log do erro:

```
Erro a partir da linha : 4 no comando -
DECLARE 
col_count  integer;
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*)
into col_count
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'populis.painel'
AND column_name = 'atrAtivoInativo';

IF col_count = 0 
THEN 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE POPULIS.PAINEL add atrAtivoInativo char(1) default 'A' not null';
END IF;
END;
Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: linha 12, coluna 88:
PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "A" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:

* & = - + ; < / > at in é mod lembrete not rem retornar
retornando <um expoente (**)> <> ou != ou ~= >= <= <> e ou
como like2 like4 likec entre into usando || multiset bulk
membro submultiset
O símbolo "* foi inserido antes de "A" para continuar.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após mais pesquisas ao colega do trabalho hehe conseguimos solucionar dessa forma:

```
/*Verifica se coluna já existe e se não houver insere com valor padrão 'A'*/
DECLARE 
col_count  integer;
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*)
into col_count
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'nomeTabela'
AND column_name = 'nomeColuna';

IF col_count = 0 THEN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE <nomeTabela> add <nomeColuna> char(1) default ''A'' not null';
COMMIT;
END IF;
exception when others then
if sqlcode = -01430 || -06512 then
null;
end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala Guilherme!

O problema está na linha:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE <nomeTabela> add <nomeColuna> char(1) default 'A' not null'
```

Conforme indicado pelo o erro:

> ORA-06550: linha 12, coluna 88

Acontece que a String que representa o seu comando de alterar a tabela está quebrada. O comando deveria estar inteiramente envolvido por apostrofes, mas perceba que quando você envolve o A com apostrofe você quebrou a String em duas ficando o comando **'ALTER TABLE  add  char(1) default'** e o **'not null'** com uma letra A no meio.

Confesso que não sei o que significa este **default 'A' not null** mas se está certo isso daí use caracteres de escape para representar estes apostrofes que envolvem o A, no caso ficaria:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE <nomeTabela> add <nomeColuna> char(1) default ''A'' not null'
```

Note que em volta do A são dois apostrofes e não aspas duplas.

Comment: Realmente eu não tinha percebido isso, e agora este comando funcionou. Mas agora eu tenho outro problema que é o fato de que esse código todo foi pra incluir uma coluna na tabela e se por acaso for executado de novo não tenta incluir essa coluna novamente na tabela; mas se eu executar de novo ele retorna erro de que a coluna já existe, precisava de alguma forma que ele não entrasse no if. E só pra te explicar quando eu coloquei **default 'A' not null** foi com a intenção de inserir uma coluna que não aceite nulos e por padrão tenha o caractere **A**. Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciaAlves talvez o usuário do banco que você está usando não é dono desta tabela. Se você rodar o comando **SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = '<nomeTabela>'** é retornado algum resultado? Se não retornar resultados você pode usar a **ALL_TAB_COLS** no lugar de **USER_TAB_COLUMNS** ou mudar esta tabela para que o dono dela seja o usuário logado. Depende da situação mas acho mais viável a primeira opção.

Comment: Executando esse comando ele retorna os campos porém vazios, agora já não sei muito o que fazer.

Comment: Desculpa @GuilhermeGarciaAlves, não entendi, a consulta **SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS where table_name = '<nome da tabela>';** não retorna resultados?

Comment: As duas retornam as colunas porém vazias, tanto a **SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS where table_name = '<nome da tabela>';** quanto **SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns where table_name = '<nome da tabela>';**

Comment: Aí já não sei como te ajudar, o que parece é que você não tem permissão para ver estas tabelas, mas o estranho é que você consegue fazer o alter table, então não sei o que pode estar acontecendo. Vi agora sua explicação do default, tem razão, usei poucas vezes o default então não lembrava disto. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma seria a seguinte:

```
/*Verifica se coluna já existe e se não houver insere com valor padrão 'A'*/
DECLARE
  va_existe integer;
  va_nome_tabela varchar2(100);
  va_nome_coluna varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
    into va_existe
    FROM user_tab_columns
   WHERE table_name = va_nome_tabela
     AND column_name = va_nome_coluna;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||va_nome_tabela||' add '||va_nome_coluna||' char(1) default ''A'' not null';
  when others then
    raise_application_error(-20001, slqerrm);
END;
```

*Como não é possível duplicar nomes de colunas em uma tabela, o resultado da query sempre será 1 registro ou nenhum registro (NO_DATA_FOUND);
**Não é necessário o comando COMMIT após a execução do comando EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, pois o comando executado (pelo EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) é um comando DDL que por padrão efetua um COMMIT antes de ser executado.